# Как значение, полученное из json сохранить в preferences?

Tags: json, java, android

Делаю вот таким образом

```
метод требует синхронизации, т.к. он вызывается из потоков тасков
    private synchronized void parsingDataInView(JSONArray jsonArray)
            throws JSONException {
        // Если первый объект имеет ключ "place", то к нам пришло место
        if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).has("place")) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            Editor editor =  myPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("place", jsonObject.getString("place"));
            editor.commit();    
    }
```

С запросами разобралась давно, здесь проблем не возникает, если просто в строку результат выводить. А вот с Preferences столкнулась первый раз. Подскажите где допустила ошибку, как сделать правильно?

Comment: А что именно не выходит? Не компилируется? При выполнении вылетает? (Если да, в какой строке?) Выполняется без видимых ошибок, но после сохранения результат фактически не записывается? Результат записывается, но проблемы со считыванием?

Comment: Да вылетает, ругается на следующие строки     Editor editor =  myPreferences.edit();   private synchronized void parsingDataInView(JSONArray jsonArray) и    parsingDataInView(new JSONArray(result)); - это уже в protected void onPostExecute(String result) .

Comment: То есть вылетает с исключением (exception)? Тогда скажите точно, в какой строке (в нескольких не может быть никак), и дайте информацию об исключении: какой его тип? какое сообщение в нём содержится?

Comment: 01-18 13:38:27.005: E/AndroidRuntime(419): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 13:38:27.005: E/AndroidRuntime(419): java.lang.NullPointerException
а дальше вот эта строка     Editor editor =  myPreferences.edit();

Comment: Видимо в этой точке выполнения кода myPreferences равен null - просто ещё не инициализирован. Такое бывает.

Comment: KoVadim, спасибо, уже разобралась.

Answer (score 1):

Просто нужно сначала создать объект myPreferences, вероятно Вы это не сделали, до того, как начали к нему обращаться.

инициализация происходит так

`myPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("тут может быть любое имя группы преференсов", 0);`

а потом уже можно пользоваться

Comment: Странно, вопрос закрыт, а ответы публиковать можно. Хм.

Comment: @VladD, вопрос не закрыт. Автор сам так написал в теме.

Comment: @Iranda: ясно, а то я подумал -- сбой в системе :-)